# Scrolling to Last Table View Cell Shows First Cell's Data

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am using UITableView with Griding Functionality. When scrolling, at the last column it automatically comes at First cell. What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: You might want to provide more information. What do you mean by "Griding Fuctionality"? How are you providing the data to the table view?

Comment: Actually In my Table 7 columns provided when i am at 7th column and scrolling i should be in 7th column but instead i reached at First column that is the problem.

Comment: Tableviews don't have columns by default. How are implementing the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looping your data source.

A tableview has some data structure that provides both the data and the structure of that data so that the data is ordered into rows. The simplest data structure would be an array. The first row would display info at array element zero, the second row at array element 1 and so on.

If the last row of the table displays data from first row, then you have somehow looped the array index back to zero. I can't say exactly how you've done that without seeing the code.